# Using Tensorflow with GPU on Debian 8.10 Jessie

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I have Tensorflow installed on the Debian Server using `virtual environment`

```
export url=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.5.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
pip3 install --user $url
```

This installs `tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0` on `~/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`

But when I import tensor flow package in Ipython notebook like:

```
 import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following error:

```
 ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In `/usr/local/cuda-8.0` I do have `./lib64/libcublas.so.8.0`. Then why can't Tensorflow find it? Now do I need to install cuda-9.0? Unfortunately, I don't have root permissions on the system. Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Yes, `tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0` uses cuda 9.0.

Comment: So, all  I need to do is execute the following command: `sudo apt-get install cuda-9.0`? Or, do I need to do some other settings in order for virtual installation of `tf-gpu` to recognize and look for cuda-9.0?

Comment: You'll need to get cuda and also cuDNN (see the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#nvidia_requirements_to_run_tensorflow_with_gpu_support)

Comment: @EvanWeissburg, thank you for the information. Installing new software is a bit difficult because I am not the admin. So I have 2 questions. Is installation of Tensorflow 1.4.0 possible? If yes,  Secondly, what version of Cuda does Tensorflow 1.4.0 use? Thanks much for your help.

Comment: Yes, in fact I am using 1.4.0 because I don't want to upgrade cuda. Find the correct binary URL to install using the Tensorflow install documentation linked.

Comment: Hi @EvanWeissburg, Yes I did that. Now it complains `ImportError: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I do have cuda-8.0. Do I need to create a soft-link somewhere locally?

Comment: Did you follow the full documentation linked when installing for all components?

Comment: Hi @EvanWeissburg, I don't really have authority to issue a `sudo` on this system. But I do see `/usr/local/cuda-8.0` folder on the system. So I am assuming the sys admin followed the documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164098/discussion-between-evan-weissburg-and-learner).